# Anyway to filter and create dataframe from user input

Tags: python, loops, data-manipulation

I've been struggling to come up with a way to filter data based on user input and create a new dataframe for each unique value. Imagine data that looks like below and can be replicated for any symbol. A user could input AAPL, AMD, MSFT. I cant seem to connect user input with a for loop that would iterate through my data and create a new dataframe of data for each symbol. So all data that has AAPL in the Symbol column would be in one dataframe, all AMD data in another, and so on for however many symbols the user inputs. I then would like to be able to pass stats.binned_statistics to each of those dataframes.

```
data = 
    {'Date': ['30 Sep 2020 09:55', '30 Sep 2020 09:55', '30 Sep 2020 09:55'], 
    'Symbol':['AAPL', 'AMD', 'MSFT'], 
    'Price':[116.35, 81.88, 208.99], 
    'Size': [90000, 200000, 750000], 
    'MoneyFlow': [10471500, 16376000, 156742500],
    '% of 14d':[0, 1, 3], 
    'Condition':['Regular','Regular','Regular']
    }
```

Comment: can you include the data for AMD and MSFT in your code?

Comment: Updated. @Andrew

Comment: your data is still malformed

Comment: @anon01 believe it should be all fixed now, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

A few general comments: it sounds like you don't need to generate new dataframes, just calculate results on a subset of your df.  You don't mention how users input info (webpage, command-line) or what statistics you want to calculate.  However, a simple example for command-line input and stats is below:

```
data = {
    'Date': ['30 Sep 2020 09:55', '30 Sep 2020 09:55', '30 Sep 2020 09:55'], 
    'Symbol':['AAPL', 'AMD', 'MSFT'], 
    'Price':[116.35, 81.88, 208.99], 
    'Size': [90000, 200000, 750000], 
    'MoneyFlow': [10471500, 16376000, 156742500],
    '% of 14d':[0, 1, 3], 
    'Condition':['Regular','Regular','Regular']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# syntax for python 3
while True:
    sym = input(f"please choose one of {df.Symbol.values}:\n")
    if sym not in df.Symbol.values:
        print(f"`{sym}` not found.")    
        continue
    else:
        view_df = df[df.Symbol == sym]
        # do whatever stats on view_df here
        print(view_df.describe(), "\n")
```

Comment: Sorry if this question is obvious, but for the else part of the if statement would that work in the way that it would only select one of the inputs entered. It would most likely be command line or filepath with excel sheet for input.    `is_stock = csv_df['Symbol'] == stock` `block_df = csv_df[is_stock]`                                                                                    is what I've been using for single input where stock would be the single symbol that user has inputted from command line to get the filtered dataframe that I can do stats on easily without mixing data points

Comment: Got it working on my end, was having indentation issues due to copy/paste. I see how it works now and it isn't exactly what I'd like to do it has given me some new ideas on how to go forward thank you